# String passed from Android POST request to PHP in server not being recognized properly in MySQL SELECT query

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

I've been hacking at this one for a while, but I can't find a good reason for the following behavior:

I have an Android app from which I send a multipart/form-data http post. The request has the following form:

```
    private final String delimiter = "--";
    private final String boundary = "SwA"
                    + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "SwA";
    private final String charset = "UTF-8";
    private final String lineSpace = "\r\n";
    private final String domain = (domain);

    private HttpURLConnection configureConnectionForMultipart(String url)
                    throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url))
                            .openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="
                            + boundary);
            return con;
    }

    private void addFormPart(String paramName, String value, DataOutputStream os)
                    throws IOException {
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace + delimiter + boundary + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName
                            + "\"" + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace + value + lineSpace);
            os.flush();
    }

    private void addFilePart(String paramName, File data, DataOutputStream os)
                    throws IOException {
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace + delimiter + boundary + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName
                            + "\"" + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineSpace);
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
            os.flush();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(data);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
            os.flush();
            fis.close();
    }

    private void finishMultipart(DataOutputStream os) throws IOException {
            os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
            os.flush();
            os.writeBytes(delimiter + boundary + delimiter + lineSpace);
            os.close();
    }

    private String getResponse(HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {
            String response = "";
            int status = con.getResponseCode();

            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    con.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            response += line;
                    }
                    reader.close();
            } else {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            response += line;
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status+", "+response);
            }
            return response;
    }


public SearchQueryRunnable initSearchQueryRunnable(String query) {
                return new SearchQueryRunnable(query);
        }


    private class SearchQueryRunnable implements Runnable {

            private final String _query;
            private final String _url = domain + "search_query.php";

            public SearchQueryRunnable(String query) {
                    _query = query;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                    try {
                            HttpURLConnection con = configureConnectionForMultipart(_url);
                            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                                            con.getOutputStream());
                            addFormPart("tag", _query, os);
                            finishMultipart(os);
                            String result = getResponse(con);
                            Log.i("SearchQuery", result);
                            con.disconnect();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }
```

In search_query.php, I have the following:

```
include 'hashtags_table_api.php';

$tag = $_POST["tag"];
$res = queryHashTagsTable($tag);
```

In hashtags_table_api.php, there is:

```
include 'connect.php';

function queryHashTagsTable($hashtag) {
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_hashtags` WHERE hashtag = :hashtag";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );
    echo $hashtag;
    $stmt->bindValue(':hashtag', $hashtag);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo count($result);
    }
}
```

connect.php is (omitted important variables):

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO ( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run this code and pass the value "hash" to initSearchQueryRunnable, I get a result of 0, even though I have a row with the value "hash" in the column hashtag.  What's weird is that when I hardcode the following in search_query.php:

```
include 'hashtags_table_api.php';

$tag = 'hash';
$res = queryHashTagsTable($tag);
```

I get the desired result of 1 from my query.  I double checked and the $_POST["tag"] is passing the value 'hash' to my server, but for some reason my SQL query will not recognize this as being equal to the value in my DB, even though the exact same hardcoded value is recognized as being equal.

Any clue what else I need to do in order to have my dynamically-passed parameter recognized as an equal value to my MySQL data?

**EDIT**

After some testing, I realized that the $_POST["tag"] is coming through with quotes, and thus strlen[$tag] = 6.  I think this might be the reason why the SQL isn't matching the query string up with what's in the db.  Sure enough strlen['hash'] = 4, which the SQL successfully matches up with my query. How can I effectively remove the quotation marks from the value of of $tag, so that my query works? FYI, my server is running PHP 5.4.24, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem here. It turns out that the text being sent through my http post had two extra invisible whitespaces that I could only detect by some tests using strlen and using a for statement to see where the spaces were being appended. My solution was to use the trim() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and just simply add $tag = trim($tag) to search_query.php before running queryHashTagsTable($tag). I hope this helps someone else that doesn't realize their http post request is being sent with extra invisible characters and needs the exact string for an sql query.